# Bash - Escaping SSH commands

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a set of scripts that I use to download files via FTP and then delete them from the server.

It works as follows:

```
for dir in `ls /volume1/auto_downloads/sync-complete`
do
if [ "x$dir" != *"x"* ]
then
echo "DIR: $dir"

echo "Moving out of complete"
        # Soft delete from server so they don't get downloaded again
        ssh dan@172.19.1.15 mv -v "'/home/dan/Downloads/complete/$dir'" /home/dan/Downloads/downloaded
```

Now $dir could be "This is a file" which works fine.

The problem I'm having is with special characters eg:

- "This is (a) file"
- This is a file & stuff"

tend to error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `mv -v '/home/dan/Downloads/complete/This is (a) file' /home/dan/Downloads/downloaded'
```

I can't work out how to escape it so both the variable gets evaluated and the command gets escaped properly. I've tried various combinations of escape characters, literal quotes, normal quotes, etc

Comment: How about `rsync --remove-source-files` http://serverfault.com/a/363925/69736 . Much easier!

Comment: It's not clear how `dir` is being set to the single string 'This is (a) file`. It should be set successively to 4 separate strings 'This', 'is', '(a)', and 'file'. Don't parse the output of `ls`; switch the directory and iterate over a glob (see my answer for details).

Comment: `[ "x$dir" != *"x"* ]` -- this only works for pattern matching in `[[`, not `[`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If both sides are using bash, you can escape the arguments using `printf '%q '`, eg:

```
ssh dan@172.19.1.15 "$(printf '%q ' mv -v "/home/dan/Downloads/complete/$dir" /home/dan/Downloads/downloaded)"
```

Comment: The `printf` is only executed on the local end, so `bash` is not needed on the remote host.

Comment: `%q` escapes according to Bash's escaping rules. If bash is not the remote shell, there is no guarantee that the escapes are valid.

Comment: ...might also consider using `printf -v cmd_q '%q ' ...`, and then `ssh user@host "$cmd_q"`, avoiding paying a subshell penalty altogether.

Comment: BTW, in modern bash (5.x certainly, maybe late 4.x), one can `ssh dan@host "mv -v /path/to/${dir@Q} /path/to/Downloads`

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the whole expression `ssh user@host "command"`:

```
ssh dan@172.19.1.15 "mv -v /home/dan/Downloads/complete/$dir /home/dan/Downloads/downloaded"
```

Comment: That resulted in the variable being evaluated on the remote end, not the local

Comment: Oh, I see. So I update my answer without the `$` escaped. It should work now.

Comment: Ah now I see you had an `echo` before the `ssh` command. So what's better doing is to wrap this inside a `$()`, as indicated by @Will Palmer answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, because your code as written works for me:

```
> dir='foo & bar (and) baz'
> ssh host  mv -v "'/home/dan/Downloads/complete/$dir'" /home/dan/Downloads/downloaded
mv: cannot stat `/home/dan/Downloads/complete/foo & bar (and) baz': No such file or directory
```

For debugging, use `set -vx` at the top of the script to see what's going on.

Comment: try with `dir="nathan's crew.txt"`

Comment: @Will, you got me on that one, so your answer is definitely better than mine, but I'm still confused as to why the OP had the problems he stated with the script he posted.

Comment: The actual problem comes from the way remote commands are passed in over SSH: All arguments are joined together and passed in to the remote shell as a single string- so those double-quotes in the original post's example are actually only there to make the single-quotes exist on the remote end.

Comment: @Will, yes, but unless `$dir` contains a single-quote (or possibly an exclamation point) it should work.  The OP said it was getting tripped up on parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Will Palmer's suggestion of using `printf` is great but I think it makes more sense to put the literal parts in `printf`'s format.

That way, multi-command one-liners are more intuitive to write:

```sh
ssh user@host "$(printf 'mkdir -p -- %q && cd -- "$_" && tar -zx' "$DIR")"
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use python `shlex.quote(s)` to

> Return a shell-escaped version of the string s

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex#shlex.quote)

Comment: This has an advantage over the `printf %q` approach insofar as the strings it returns are guaranteed to work on all POSIX-compliant shells, not just bash.