# How do I list manually installed packages in Debian over SSH non-interactively?

Tags: ssh, debian, aptitude

Directly on my Debian box, I can run the following command to show manually installed packages:

```
aptitude search '!~M ~i'
```

This works great. If I SSH in from a remote box, and run the command, I also get the same result.

However, when I run the command as a batch, it does not produce the same result.

```
ssh user@server aptitude search '!~M ~i'
```

Since the process takes a bit of time to run, I execute `ps aux | grep aptitude` while running both variants, and the result appears to be the same.

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I am aware that dpkg -L can produce this information, but this is just the smallest example of what is broken, I intend to use `!~pstandard !~pimportant !~prequired` to filter out base packages as well, which I don't believe dpkg can do (but if it can, a solution with dpkg is welcome.)

Answer (score 1):

Using information from [Bash - Escaping SSH commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887513/bash-escaping-ssh-commands), I was able to create a command that worked:

```
ssh user@server $(printf '%q ' aptitude search '!~M ~i')
```

Answer (score 1):

If target is a more recent debian/ubuntu you can use:

`ssh user@server apt-mark showmanual`